# Odoo 9 how to correctly concat two chars?

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-9

I have 3 fields and trying to concat fields so char3=char1+char2

Wrote the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from openerp import models, fields, api
from openerp.tools import ustr

class pucrhase_order_pref_supplier(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'purchase.order.line'
#this field will be displayed on the product list in the purchase order
    preferred_supplier_product = fields.Char(related="product_id.preferred_supplier_middle", string="Preferred Supplier", readonly="true")
    preferred_supplier_template = fields.Char(related="product_id.preferred_supplier_middle", string="Preferred Supplier", readonly="true")
    preferred_supplier = fields.Char(compute='_onchange_proc', store="True")

@api.one
@api.depends('preferred_supplier','preferred_supplier_product','preferred_supplier_template')
def _onchange_proc(self):
        string1 = self.preferred_supplier_product
        string2 = self.preferred_supplier_template
        output = ustr(string1)+"-"+ustr(string2)
        self.preferred_supplier = output
```

Not sure why but preferred_supplier is not calculated (other fields works fine). Should I use onchange instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can concat two string by following method:

```
@api.onchange('char1', 'char2')
def _onchange_weight_range(self):
    list = []
    if self.char1:
        conc = str(self.char1 or '') + '-' + str(self.char2 or '')
        list.append(conc)
        self.char3 = ', '.join(list)
```

Comment: Python is not for complicating things. For a small operation you write all of this code!!

Answer (score 1):

The list of field in depends should not contains the same field that is computed. And don't depends on related field use DOT to go deeper in the other model

```py
 # no need to create related fields if you are not showing them in your form view

 @api.depends('product_id', 'product_id.preferred_supplier_middle',
               'product_id.preferred_supplier_middle')
 def _onchange_proc(self):
      # I prefer using string formatting for this kind of work
      self.preferred_supplier = '%s-%s' % (product_id.preferred_supplier_middle or '', product_id.preferred_supplier_middle or '')
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all a few comments on the code itself:
preferred_supplier_product and preferred_supplier_template are related to exactly the same field, I don't think it's supposed to be.

Just as Cherif stated if you don't even need the fields in your view there's no need to create them

I'd use the Python True / False for the readonly/store attributes of the fields instead of a string.

Why does the computation depend on itself?

Now for your answer:

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('preferred_supplier_product', 'preferred_supplier_template')
def _onchange_proc(self):
    for record in self:
        record.preferred_supplier = '%s-%s' % (record.preferred_supplier_product, record.preferred_supplier_template)
```

Or depending if you need the fields declared for your view or not

```
@api.multi
@api.depends('product_id.preferred_supplier_middle')
def _onchange_proc(self):
    for record in self:
        record.preferred_supplier = '%s-%s' % (
            record.product_id.preferred_supplier_middle, record.product_id.preferred_supplier_middle)
```